# Compare three array of objects using Id from one array to another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am basically trying to get all the data from one array of objects from another.
for example:

```
first_array = [{id: 1, name:'something'},{id: 2, name:'something 2'},{id: 3, name:'something 3'},{id: 4, name:'something 4'}]
```

now this array can have thousands of objects.

the next array is

```
 second_array = [{idx: 40, name:'something',matchingId:1 },{idx: 30, name:'something 2'},{idx: 60, name:'something 3',matchingId:1 },{idx: 20, name:'something 4',matchingId:2},{idx: 25, name:'something 4',matchingId:2},{idx: 26, name:'something 4',matchingId:3}]
```

now using matchingId from this second_array i want to get elements from first_array and then return all the objects.Now using the newly created array i want to find all the elements inside the third_array with the same id.

```
third_array = [{id: 1, name:'something',matchingIdFromSecond:40 },{id: 2, name:'something 2'},{id: 3, name:'something 3',matchingIdFromSecond:40 },{id: 3, name:'something 4',matchingIdFromSecond:30},{id: 4, name:'something 4',matchingIdFromSecond:2},{id: 5, name:'something 4',matchingIdFromSecond:26}]
```

So overall i am trying to implement a join with 3 tables but with vanialla js code.

I tried using the filter and the mapping over the result to third_array but it is not working.

This is what i am trying the achieve the overall flow

```
first_array -> use id
 second_array -> first_array_ids be matched with second_array.matchingId
 third_array -> data returned from second_array use id, and then find all the elements inside third_array.
```

Hope i made my self clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+compare+array+id+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can just map the first array and find the corresponding indexes from the second array like so:

```js
const first_array = [{id: 1, name:'something'},{id: 2, name:'something 2'},{id: 3, name:'something 3'},{id: 4, name:'something 4'}];
const second_array = [{idx: 40, name:'something',matchingId:1 },{idx: 30, name:'something 2'},{idx: 60, name:'something 3',matchingId:1 },{idx: 20, name:'something 4',matchingId:2},{idx: 25, name:'something 4',matchingId:2},{idx: 26, name:'something 4',matchingId:3}];

const third_array = first_array.map(el => ({
  // add back all the original properties to the new object
  ...el,
  // find the matching id -> if one exists, choose the index
  matchingId: second_array.find(subEl => subEl.matchingId === el.id)?.idx
}));

console.log(third_array);
```

In case there are any questions left on specific parts:

- [`...` → named Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`find(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [`?.` → named Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

If you can't use some operators from the snippet, you might look into `Babel` to transpile your code: https://babeljs.io/repl

[Here is a transpiled version of this snippet](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?browsers=defaults%0A&build=&builtIns=false&corejs=3.6&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwE7QPoEMlPQTxgXhgG0BvBAEwC4YBGAGhjHQFsBTSgcghDagAsEYAOYcAvnTJUYAJgZM2nbrwHCZYiRWoBmOS3ZcerfoKEwt6ydQAsuhQeUmYVsQF0A3AChQkWBFbfyDCxcAmJJAA9rAAZbfSUjFRE6ZnQoYESASSoaGHEI7RjGPUVDY1VpCwpImAA2Qvk40sSzDmTU9JMsyhy8quppeuL7BMdnNrTMqmle8mrpAFZYkodVMZSJzqmZuZql4bLTNfbJyi1Rdw8vcGgYYyRAzGw8QkQUKCCngDoUgAcAClYABsCAA-GB_EgeGAwAD0MJg6HI5BgACN0MAANYIwHA_isGAgJAIISCdDAn5IEA_VhIKAIVgQW4gW58fFgVgAdwJKIAVv4oFCYJ9hUC6IK4fBBMi8TB1h1VBQYABaMEIOAE9kwVjhBDQCAMdIgEB-Fn4qXawVyk4wPwBD64T6IMDkP4QACuKIAosD8GD3V7Ad9jpsCPhCEDPhQAJQAfkjsw8oijUc8V0gIEBrE-gJAQj-dwewRwKaAA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=script&lineWrap=false&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.14.7&externalPlugins=)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you have `matchingId` missing in second_array and `matchingIdFromSecond` missing from third_array

In such situations, you might have to decide which join type do you intend to use. I've shared implementation of inner_join,

```js
const first_array = [
  { id: 1, name: 'something' },
  { id: 2, name: 'something 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'something 3' },
  { id: 4, name: 'something 4' },
]
const second_array = [
  { idx: 40, name: 'something', matchingId: 1 },
  { idx: 30, name: 'something 2' },
  { idx: 60, name: 'something 3', matchingId: 1 },
  { idx: 20, name: 'something 4', matchingId: 2 },
  { idx: 25, name: 'something 4', matchingId: 2 },
  { idx: 26, name: 'something 4', matchingId: 3 },
]
const third_array = [
  { id: 1, name: 'something', matchingIdFromSecond: 40 },
  { id: 2, name: 'something 2' },
  { id: 3, name: 'something 3', matchingIdFromSecond: 40 },
  { id: 3, name: 'something 4', matchingIdFromSecond: 30 },
  { id: 4, name: 'something 4', matchingIdFromSecond: 2 },
  { id: 5, name: 'something 4', matchingIdFromSecond: 26 },
]

const inner_join = third_array.map((item3) => {
  const matches2 = second_array.filter((val2) => val2.idx === item3.matchingIdFromSecond)
  const matches21 = matches2.map(match2 => first_array.filter((val1) => val1.id === match2.matchingId))

    return matches21.map((matches1, i) => (matches1.map(match1 => ({
        ...item3,
        match1,
        match2: matches2[i],
    }))))
}).flat(2)

console.log('inner_join', inner_join)
```

For a cleaner and more robust code, prefer using [lodash-joins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-joins) npm library where you can imitate my output(with `match1`, `match2` absorbed into parent object) by

```js
const output2 = _.hashInnerJoin(
  _.hashInnerJoin(third_array, 'matchingIdFromSecond', second_array, 'idx'),
  'matchingId',
  first_array,
  'id'
)
```

EDIT: I went on to verify the outputs by running same in SQL. Sharing the code for reference.

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1  (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(30));
CREATE TABLE t2 (idx INTEGER, name VARCHAR(30), matchingId INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE t3 (id INTEGER, name VARCHAR(30), matchingIdFromSecond INTEGER);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1, "something"), (2, "something 2"), (3, "something 3"), (4, "something 4");
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (40,"something",1),(30,"something 2", NULL),(60,"something 3",1),(20,"something 4",2),(25,"something 4",2),(26,"something 4",3);
insert into t3 values (1,"something",40),(2,"something 2", NULL),(3,"something 3",40),(3,"something 4",30),(4,"something 4",2),(5,"something 4",26);

SELECT * from t3 join t2 on t3.matchingIdFromSecond = t2.idx join t1 on t1.id = t2.matchingId;
```